# How to get rid of last characters of a pandas object?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I created a python script to scrape Yahoo finance to extract some data;
so created a method that extract a table and display it as a pandas table for example;

f = get_stock_info('AAPL') with output

```
                               Value
Label                               
Market Cap (intraday) 5       815.6B
Enterprise Value 3           834.29B
Trailing P/E                   14.27
Forward P/E 1                  13.57
PEG Ratio (5 yr expected) 1     1.15
Price/Sales (ttm)               3.12
Price/Book (mrq)                6.94
Enterprise Value/Revenue 3      3.19
Enterprise Value/EBITDA 6      10.49
```

I would like to be able to transform this table from object to Float type so I would need to get rid of the B in 815.6B and 834.29B

I tried:

```
x = f.loc["Market Cap (intraday) 5"][0][:-1]
```

which output 815.6

then `f.loc["Market Cap (intraday) 5"][0] = f.loc["Market Cap (intraday) 5"][0][:-1]`

but the output is 815 and not 816.6

Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Something like `f['Value'] = f['Value'].str.replace('B', '', regex=False)`

Comment: use: `df.Value.replace('[a-zA-Z]','',regex=True)`

Comment: Though there's likely also `'M'` and `'K'` which need to be replaced to. Perhaps `extract` the decimal number, or just replace all three.

Comment: f.loc['Value'] = f.loc['Value'].str.replace('B', '', regex=False) worked for me thx yo uvery much